# SharePoint 2010 REST - $COUNT Display

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Could someone tell me why this isn't working?

```
$(function() {

fnWaitDialog("show");

$.getJSON(".../List/$count?$expand=AARMissionTypeValue&$filter=AARMissionTypeValue eq 'Special Events Security'", function (data) {

        var d = data.d;
        $.each(data.d, function (n, i) {

            $("#tableBodyCount").append(i.count);
        });

})

    .always(function () {
    // Close spinner
    fnWaitDialog("hide");
});
```

I can't seem to get it to display in the id of my spam to show a document count. It works when you use the URL.

Edit:

I got it to return a number but it should be 6 but it returns 66...

```
var count = data.d.results.length;
        $.each(data.d, function (n, i) {

            $("#tableBodyCount").append(count);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect $.each function prints value twice.

Do one thing alert out alert(data.d.results.length); and if you are getting 6 then $.each causing it to print twice then change ur code as per below code.

Instead of

```
var count = data.d.results.length;
        $.each(data.d, function (n, i) {

            $("#tableBodyCount").append(count);
        });
```

try this

```
var count = data.d.results.length;
$("#tableBodyCount").text(count);
```

Test the code with uploading or deleting few more documents.